# When to use ":="?

Tags: notation, proof-writing, article-writing

I know that "$:=$" is used in definitions. For example, one can write:

> $A\times B:=\{(a, b)\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$

But would you use "$:=$" in the following example:

> Let a function $f\colon A\to \{0, 1\}^A$ be given. Define $g\colon A\to\{0, 1\}$ as follows: For each $a\in A$, set $g(a):=0$ if $(f(a))(a)=1$ and $g(a):=1$ if $(f(a))(a)=0$.

?

Comment: It is not essential. Use whatever convention you prefer. The most important information is in the words you use, "For each [...] set".

Comment: Basically, "$=$" is overloaded. It means 1) Two expressions are always equal (identity). Example: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$. 2) Two expressions are suppopsed to be equal in some cases (equation). Example: $x^2 +4x + 3 = 0$ 3) One side is made so that the two sides are always equal (definition). Example: $\pi = \frac{\text{circumference}}{\text{diameter}}$. Some have no problems using the same symbol for all these, some like to use different symbols (usually $\equiv$, $=$ and $:=$ respectively, but there are variations).

Comment: Just my two cents: I would omit the colon in your example. The intended sense of the equal sign is already clear from your sentence. Omitting the colon makes the sentence simpler.